# Cant install a library from pod in IOS which internally uses rust

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am trying to install [libsignal-client](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client) through the pod. It uses a rust encryption library internally.

Error is given compiling `libsignal-ffi`:

```
 Compiling libsignal-ffi v0.9.4 (/Users/tanmoy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/SignalClient/94c18a0d31671033b99c08bafb98f6e4/rust/bridge/ffi)
    Finished release [optimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2m 38s
warning: Building using xargo to support tier 3 target aarch64-apple-ios-sim.
error: `rust-src` component not found. Run `rustup component add rust-src`.
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace
```

Based on the [source](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client) repository,

`https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client/blob/master/rust-toolchain`

I used the exact same `rust-src`

```sh
export XARGO_RUST_SRC=/Users/tanmoy/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library
```

This time another error building `std`.

```
 Compiling std v0.0.0 (/Users/tanmoy/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std)
error[E0557]: feature has been removed
   --> /Users/tanmoy/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/lib.rs:102:37

.....

error: aborting due to 325 previous errors; 7 warnings emitted

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0307, E0522, E0557, E0658.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `core`
```

Been trying different solutions but none seems to work. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client/issues/361) issue, the two alternative solution was

- Running `rustup +nightly-2021-06-08 component add rust-src`

  - All five architectures supported

    - aarch64-apple-io
    - x86_64-apple-ios
    - aarch64-apple-ios-sim
    - x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
    - aarch64-apple-ios-macabi
- Proceed with default installation [guide](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client)

  - Comment out tier3 architecture here [SignalClient.podspec](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client/blob/master/SignalClient.podspec)
  - Two architectures supported

    - aarch64-apple-io
    - x86_64-apple-ios

Answer (score 0):

Add Rush in iOS Mobile App project for Xcode
Follow simple Steps

**Run these Command one by one**

```
   curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

   rustup update
   rustup toolchain install nightly
   rustup default nightly

   rustup target add aarch64-apple-ios
```

**Upwote and like :)**